# Javascript Extract Tokens from String into Array

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like: `The zoo has a panda named {{123}} that is colored {{234}}`

I have an array that represents each one of the tokens like:

`[ { label: 'Ralph', id: '123' }, { label: 'White and Black', id: '234' } ]`

I want to traverse the string and replace the `{{token}}` with the actual label BUT i also need to keep track of the character position that I'm replacing. Ralph would be position 26 character.  A trickier scenario would be: after I replace `{{123}}` with `Ralph` the text position of color would be different since Ralph is 5 characters and the token was 7 characters.

Any thoughts on the fastest approach to solving this?

Comment: Try to first solve your problem. From there on, try to optimise it.

Comment: what would be the regex to grab all the matches and get the indexes?  I guess thats my missing piece.

Comment: @amcdnl why a regex ? `indexOf()`is great

Comment: Why do you need the indexes? And do you need them as of **before** any replacements were done, or after replacements leading up to that token were done, or...?

Comment: @amcdnl: What exactly are you trying to do? Are you __only__ simply trying to replace the `{{tokens}}`? Or do you need the indexes for something else?

Comment: @Hacketo ya, i was totally overthinking it!  indexOf is perfect.  sometimes it just helps to brainstorm with others.

Answer (score 7):

This may not be as hard as you'd imagine:

```js
var str = "The zoo has a panda named {{123}} that is colored {{234}}";
var array = [ { label: 'Ralph', id: '123' }, { label: 'White and Black', id: '234' } ];

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
  str = str.replace("{{" + array[i].id + "}}", array[i].label);
}
alert(str);
```

Simply loop over the array and replace each key in the string with the desired label. If the key isn't found in the string, the `replace` simply does nothing.

Comment: OP also wants the indexes of the replaced items, although it's unclear why, or in what form.

Comment: @PaulRoub: My guess is that he wants the indexes for `substring`-like methods he shouldn't be using in the first place.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73256/discussion-on-answer-by-cerbrus-javascript-extract-tokens-from-string-into-array).

Comment: @bluefeet: There were actually some useful comments in there, relevant to the answer ([example](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/22165661#22165661)).... I agree the 2nd half didn't add any value though. (Thanks for moving back those)

Comment: All the comments are in the chatroom, it was getting a bit out of hand here raising an auto-flag. Since the discussion was still happening, I moved it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want track token position you can use [`String.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to split on each token, then you don't have to care about the indexes.

```
var str = "The zoo has a panda named {{123}} that is colored {{234}}";
str.split(/\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g);

//["The zoo has a panda named ", "123", " that is colored ", "234", ""]
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hacketo/6wdhn7dx/) example of use